# Angle Brackets on Indices

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, index-notation

I am reading an article where a number of derivatives appear with the indices in angle brackets, and was unsure what is meant to denote.  For example, one of them is

$\frac{\partial \hat{u}_{<i}}{\partial \hat{x}_{k>}}.$

If anyone needs a reference for the article, it is [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/02786826.2011.569777), equations 14.

Comment: The article defines the notation when it is first used (equation 13).

Comment: I should have read the article more closely to be fair, however I did realise what the definition must be in the meantime without looking.

Comment: I see what the notation means theoretically, but not sure how to work with it, for example what would be the Fourier transform of the above derivative defined in that way?